# Are ACK sent for window size updates counted toward the increment of the congestion window?

Tags: networking, tcp

Basically, that. I have taken a TCP traffic capture using WireShark and I was wondering if the ACKs sent by the client host go toward the increment of the congestion window in the server host. Like, for instance, if in slow start, each ACK sent for a window size update makes the congestion window grow in 1 MSS.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically,tcp's behaviour is just as what your said.
That, if tcp is ack-count based, in slow start, one ack causes the cwnd to increase by one.  if tcp is byte-count, in slow start, the cwnd is increased by the number of bytes acked.